# iOS add constraint to table section header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, constraints

I am working with a grouped table, and am customizing the header in the sections using tableView: viewForHeaderInSection: method and setting the height using tableView: heightForHeaderInSection:.

I created a view and placed a label in it like so:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    // Create a custom title view.
    UIView *ctv;
    UILabel *titleLabel;

    // Set the name.
    {...} // Code not relevant

    // If an iPhone.
    if ([Config isPhone]) {
        ctv = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 14, 320, 36)];
    }
    // If an iPad
    else {
        ctv = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 75)];
        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 544, 55)];
    }

    // Config the label.
    {...} // Code not relevant

    // Center the items.
    ctv.center = CGPointMake(tableView.center.x, ctv.center.y);
    titleLabel.center = ctv.center;

    // Add the label to the container view.
    [ctv addSubview:titleLabel];

    // Return the custom title view.
    return ctv;


}
```

This all works great until you rotate the screen. The position is off.  I realize that this is because the view is being centered while it is in the other orientation causing the calculation of the center to no longer be correct.  The solution should be to add a constraint.  I tried adding the constraint below:

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(ctv);
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[ctv]|"
                         options:0
                         metrics:nil
                         views:viewsDictionary
                       ];
[tableView addConstraints:constraints];
```

But when I do this trying the method below, I get that no parent view is associated with it, which makes complete sense, because it doesn't technically get added into the view is returned.  So I thought I would try to add the constraint this way:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:ctv
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                        toItem:tableView
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                    multiplier:1.0
                                      constant:0
                                      ];
[tableView addConstraint:constraint];
```

But this one also errors.  I've tried switching the tableView variables to the global table property but it gives the same results.  I also tried to figure out how to add the constraint in the view did load method but it failed as I could not figure out how to get back to the table's section headers from the table object.  The last thought I had was to set the width on the table in a constraint and set one to center the entire table. This process worked but now I have the an ugly scroll in the middle of my app when it is in the landscape orientation.  So the question is, where/how can I access the individual section headers after they have been loaded to add this constraint? I'm still pretty new to Objective-C so any help is appreciated.

***** NEW CODE BASED FROM rdelmar SUGGESTION ****

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *ctv = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"groupHeader"];
    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 544, 55)];
    [titleLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:ctv
                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                        relatedBy:0
                                          toItem:titleLabel
                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                       multiplier:1.0
                                         constant:0
                                      ];
    [ctv addConstraints:@[constraint]];
    titleLabel.text = @"string";
    [ctv addSubview:titleLabel];
    return ctv;
}
```

But like I mentioned, it is giving me a "Constraint must contain a first layout item" error.

Comment: Do you need to add a constraint to the header view? I'm not sure you do. I think you can create it with CGRectZero, and set its height in heightForHeaderInSection. I'm pretty sure the width will be whatever the table width is.

Comment: So initiate the view and label without their frames?  The main reason I was trying to keep the width of the ctv to the width I have set an image in the table header. Maybe i can try and add the constraint and width to the label and not the view and initiate the view without the frame (if I can do that... I will have to look it up... sorry noob).

Comment: Yes, you can set up constraints (and probably should) for any of the subviews of the header.

Comment: Well that kind of worked.  Didn't solve the problem, but I didn't get a flat out error. I'm getting conflict constraints yet I have no other constraints set on the section header, so not really sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't get the constraints to work, your original code supplemented by an autoresizing mask (flexible left and right margins) would do the job.

An even simpler solution would be to return a UILabel as the header view, with centered text.

Your first attempt at constraints wouldn't work because you are setting them up wrong.

The table view is responsible for setting the frame of the header view. You need to worry about the position of the label *within* the header. The VFL for this would be `"|titleLabel|"` - the title label should be sized to its superview, the header view.

Comment: Thank you.  The autoresizing mask worked... I wish I would have know about that one a little sooner. :)

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way in a recent project to add a label and a UIActivityIndicatorView:

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *headerView = [self.tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"Header"];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 250, 20)];
    [label setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    NSLayoutConstraint *con1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:headerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:0 toItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *con2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:headerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:0 toItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1 constant:-10];
    [headerView addConstraints:@[con1,con2]];
    label.text = @"Pick an Activity from the List";
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [headerView addSubview:label];
    spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    [spinner setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    if (activityIndicatorShouldStop == NO) [spinner startAnimating];
    [headerView addSubview:spinner];
    NSLayoutConstraint *con3 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:headerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:0 toItem:spinner attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *con4 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:headerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:0 toItem:spinner attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1 constant:10];
    [headerView addConstraints:@[con3,con4]];
    return headerView;
}
```

Comment: what does the spinner part do? Is that just another element on your headerView or is that portion needed to make it adjust?  I am getting an error when I just added the label constraint to the header view.

Comment: I am getting "Constraint must contain a first layout item" I will post an answer with my code based on your suggestion.

Comment: @Coyote6, make sure that ctv is not nil. Did you register a class or nib with that same reuse identifier? And, yes, spinner is just another subview I'm adding, it has nothing to do with the label.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  No, I messed that part up apparently. I got my original code to work with the autoresizing mask option as per rjturton's suggestion... It's just one of those things that is tough coming from a web programming background, I don't know all the properties and methods available to me yet.  And don't know all of the required protocol for certain functions.